# How to change file_extension internally in Blender 2.65

Tags: python, blender

I am writing a python script for Blender and I am quite new. I want to change output file format in render option internally. For example, `context.scene.render.file_extension = "PNG"` . But it is a read-only variable so I get an error. Is there a way to change it in code?

I am using Blender-2.65.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the image settings like so:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
```

My Blender version (2.66 on Windows) tells me I have the option to choose between:

```
('BMP', 'IRIS', 'PNG', 'JPEG', 'JPEG2000', 'TARGA', 'TARGA_RAW', 'CINEON', 'DPX', 'OPEN_EXR_MULTILAYER', 'OPEN_EXR', 'HDR', 'TIFF', 'AVI_JPEG', 'AVI_RAW', 'FRAMESERVER', 'H264', 'FFMPEG', 'THEORA', 'XVID')
```